# ADFS 3.0 redirects the request to internal IP instead of DNS

Tags: adfs3.0

I have configured ADFS 3.0 in my lab and trying to integrate with Salesforece. When I try to access the SalesForce using ADFS. It redirects me to ADFS login page which is expected behavior but after entering the credentials, it automatically redirect to internal IP Address instead of DNS name. I have checked on ADFS server but nothing found abnormal.

**First URL (Login Page)**

https://adfs.mycompany.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=

**After entering the credentails, redirects to below URL**

https://10.25.218.25/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=

Please help.

End point URL : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k1cb.png

Comment: What ADFS endpoints have you configured?

Comment: I configured ADFS 3.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Endpoint URL are attached